# How to print equation with correct signs in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sign

Basically, I have to print an equation with correct signage on all numbers. my current code is:

```
printf("%dx^2+%dx+%d=0", a, b, c);
```

Considering I already have values for a, b, and c, I expected this to work. However, negative numbers mess this up because if I set

> a = 2, b = 2, c = -2

(just an example), it will output

> 2x^2+2+-2=0

This obviously doesn't look right, so how can I set it so the plus sign will no longer be there if it is a negative number? My only idea was to remove all of the plus signs, but then I would get

> 2x^22-2=0

which also doesn't work. I know this may be an easy fix, but I am new to this and any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Fixed this by myself literally within seconds of posting this, all i did was put the plus sign after the % ("%dx^2%+dx%+d=0"). Leaving this up though in case anyone else has the same dumb problem as I did

Comment: If you're going to leave this up, you should eventually post an answer with your discovery. Ideally, also provide a link to  a reputable source of information if people want to know more. Do *not* post a link-only answer. Elaborate and summarize whatever information you link in your answer.  For reference, the documentation for `printf`, and as it relates to this question, the `+` sign modifier behavior, [can be seen *here*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 6):

You can easily accomplish the output you desire using `printf` *flag character* `'+'`. Specifically from `man 3 printf`:

> **Flag characters**
>
> ```
> +      A sign (+ or -) should always be placed before a number produced
>        by  a  signed  conversion.   By default, a sign is used only for 
>        negative numbers.  A + overrides a space if both are used.
> ```

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int a = 2, b = 2, c = -2;

    printf ("%dx^2%+dx%+d = 0\n", a, b, c);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/printfsign
2x^2+2x-2 = 0
```

Look things over and let me know if that is what you intended.